# Tortoise SVN Merge daimond structure issue

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, branching-and-merging

I am using Tortoise SVN and facing tree conflicts while merging code of two branches into trunk.

I have created two branches from the trunk, for example `devA` and `devB`. Now some of the code that has to be done with branch `devA` is checked in on the trunk before creating the branches. Now after completing development I merged `devA` code to the trunk but when I tried to merge Branch devB code into trunk I am getting tree conflict on the files which are common to both branches.

I am using `Reintegrate a branch` option. Let me know if more information required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tree conflicts appear, in your specific case, when you are adding files that are already added.

You just need to check if the merged files has the right content and mark the files as resolved using the option <kbd>TortoiseSVN</kbd> > <kbd>Mark As Resolved</kbd>.